# How to make a single query to retrieve objects related to a model through a join table in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-many

I have models related as follows:

```
Country 
  has_many :states

State 
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :counties

County 
  belongs_to :State
  has_many :municipalities
  has_many :cities, through: :municipalities

City
  has_many :municipalities
  has_many :counties, through: :municipalities 

Municipality
  belongs_to :county
  belongs_to :city
```

I'd like to be able to call something like @country.cities and have it return all the cities that belong to a country through its related objects. Any feedback is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Country 
  has_many :states
  has_many :counties      , through: :states
  has_many :municipalities, through: :counties
  has_many :cities        , through: :municipalities
```

Comment: This does not work. when I nest the associations as you have, and call @country.cities I get an `undefined method class_name' for nil:NilClass` error. I believe the active_record query is built off the belongs_to piece, because I've even added a municipality_id to my cities, and it still give me the same error. Heres the gist: https://gist.github.com/bjlinville1/8425bfe88bc7060209e8

Comment: please tell me I'm wrong. I'm completely stumped and have spent way to much time on this. If you see any mistakes on the gist, please let me know. I believe you SHOULD be right, but I keep coming up empty

Comment: Typo on line 4 of county.rb.

Comment: Blessed be the helpers of the blind for ye shall inherit the reputation!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Country
  has_many :states
  has_many :cities, through: :states

State
  has_many :counties
  has_many :cities, through: :counties
```

Comment: also would have worked had there not been a typo. thanks